# Any way of saving & using this context in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an existing angular 1.4 application  I want to port to typescript.
Suppose I have the following typescript class:

```
class my {
  constructor(public msg: string) {     
  }

  a() {
    alert(this.msg);
  }
}
```

I want both the calls below to do the same thing:

```
var a = new my('hello');
a.a();
var fn = a.a;
fn();
```

However, fn doesn't work, it's losing its scope. I know I can use fat arrow syntax ( `a = () => {}` ) to save the scope for a single method.

I'd want a more elegant solution, to save the this scope inside a variable and always have access to it, without having to declare each of my methods with fat arrow.

---

UPDATE: Sorry for the ambiguity, what I am looking for is a typescript class that will output the following Javascipt (notice the _self variable and its usage):

```
 var my = (function () {
  var self = this;
  function my(msg) {
    self.msg = msg;
  }
  my.prototype.a = function () {
    alert(self.msg);
  };
  return my;
}());
```

Comment: This would definitely change the nature of JavaScript to behave this way automatically. Why do you want this behavior? There's definitely not currently a way to do this in TypeScript.

Comment: creating a temp var for self is exactly what I do; I have the same issue but it's more about me having a named function inside of a method of a class. see the docs, which never mentions this workaround: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var instance = new my('hello');
instance.a(); // Call instance method
var fn = instance.a.bind(instance); // Get bound method
fn(); // Call bound method
```

#### Update 1.

What do you think about using the method to obtain bound method from class:

```
function getBoundMethod(instance, methodName) {
    return instance[methodName].bind(instance);
}

var instance = new my('hello');
instance.a(); // Call instance method
var fn = getBoundMethod(instance, "a"); // Get bound method
fn(); // Call bound method
```

Comment: TSV, unfortunately, bind / call / apply are not a solution in my case.

Comment: @ra00l IMHO the fat arrow is the only solution in this case

Comment: I suspect so as well, but I'm still hoping Typescript has a flag / synthax I don't know about